# Save the state of QCheckBox in file, and load the state when program restarts

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qcheckbox

In my GUI application, I have some labels in my mainwindow the visibility of the labels are controlled from checkboxes in a dialog which opens when a button (setting) is pressed. Now, it all works fine, i.e. if I open the settings dialog I can check or uncheck the checkboxes; consequently the labels are also set visible or invisible.

**mysettingsdialog.cpp**

```
void mysettingsdialog::onclick(bool checked)      //by AJ kpi conf
{
    if(myCheckBox->isChecked()==true)
    {
        emit setlabelvisible();
    }
    else
    {
        emit setlabelinvisible();
    }
}
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
MySettingsDialog* myset=new MySettingsDialog(this);
connect(myset,SIGNAL(setlabelvisible()),this,SLOT(enable1()));          
connect(myset,SIGNAL(setlabelinvisible()),this,SLOT(disable1()));

void MainWindow::enable1()      
{
    ui->label->setVisible(true);
    qDebug()<<"VISIBLE label";
}
void MainWindow::disable1()     
{
    ui->label->setVisible(false);
    qDebug()<<"INVISIBLE label";
}
```

Now the problem is, every time my application restarts it does not retain the previous state of the checkboxes. So I was thinking to save the state of the checkbox in a variable and writing it to a file, so whenever my application starts it will read the file and set the status of check box accordingly.

My question is, how can I store the "state" of checkbox in a variable and write it to file. And again use the same to set the state of checkbox ???

I mean reading / writing values from file for QLabels and QLineEdits is easy enough but I am baffled about how to do it with checkbox.

Comment: As Tay pointed out, the state of a checkbox is simply a `bool`. For storing it in a file you can `static_cast` it into an integer resulting in 1 for true and 0 for false

Comment: @Bowdzone Just mention there is a **tri-state** check box, so the state of a check box is not always a `bool`. Take a look at my edit for more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a container to store the pointer of each checkbox.
2. Create another container to store the "state" of each checkbox. For a binary check box, you can use [`isChecked()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#checked-prop) to query whether or not a checkbox is checked. Otherwise you can call [`checkState()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcheckbox.html#checkState) to return the state as enum if you use a tri-state check box (see the edit).
3. When loading settings, assign the state to each check box accordingly.
4. You may use [`QSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html#details) to manage the settings and save them as an *ini* file.

---

### Edit

Just mention there is an option for a tri-state check box. From [the document](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/QCheckBox.html):

> `QCheckBox` optionally provides **a third state** to indicate "no change".
>   This is useful whenever you need to give the user the option of
>   neither checking nor unchecking a checkbox. If you need this third
>   state, enable it with **`setTristate()`**, and use **`checkState()`** to query the
>   current toggle state.

Comment: well, gone through QSettings, i think using qsettings will be better for my app.. thanks..